# get_template_directory_uri() omitting space in folder path on header.php but not in the customizer.php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So, I'm trying to allow users to change default images of a theme in the customizer. Obviously I want the default images to show up first until they add their own.

In the `header.php` I have the following code:

```
                    <?php
                $sldimages = ''; 
                $sldimages = array(
                            '1' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/slides/slider1.jpg',
                            '2' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/slides/slider2.jpg',
                            '3' => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/slides/slider3.jpg',
                ); ?>
```

In the `customizer.php` I have the following code:

```
    $wp_customize->add_setting('slide_image1',array(
    'default'   => get_template_directory_uri().'/images/slides/slider1.jpg',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw',
));
$wp_customize->add_control(   new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'slide_image1', array(
        'label' => __('Slide Image 1 ','forest-lights'),
        'section' => 'slider_section',
        'settings' => 'slide_image1'
        )
     )
);
```

The issue is that when you are NOT in the Customize area, the images do not show because the filepath is incorrect. Upon inspecting the element I get:

```
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/Forestights/images/slides/slider1.jpg" alt="" title="#slidecaption1" data-pin-nopin="true">
```

When I open the customizer (and the image IS showing), I get the following file path:

```
<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/Forest%20Lights/images/slides/slider1.jpg" alt="" title="#slidecaption1">
```

The issue appears to be that when I am NOT in the customizer, the get_template_directory_uri() is omitting the space found in my theme folder title "Forest Lights" yet it doesn't in the customizer. Is there a solution for this and if so, what is it??

Comment: Spaces in file and folder paths are a bad idea altogether. Change the name of the theme folder, it won't affect the theme itself, and eventually you'll be glad you did - this will only ever cause you a headache.